# semi-log scale linear regression [Gnuplot]

Tags: graph, gnuplot, logarithm

I have an experimental data set that I linearize on a semi-log scale and of which I want to run a linear regression.

The problem is that when I set a line as a function for the fit, it, and the subsequent plot, do not give valid results since I have the y in logarithmic scale.

```
set logscale y
plot 'file.txt' u 1:2
f(x)=m*x+q
fit f(x) 'file.txt' u 1:2 via m,q
plot 'file.txt' u 1:2, f(x)
```

And the result is as shown in the image, clearly the angular coefficient is off, and I'd like to figure out how to do a linear regression when I'm on a semi-log scale.

[image: My bad fit]

#EDIT 1: As suggested I did the fit in this way

```
fit f(x) 'file.txt' u 1:(log($2)) via m,q
```

the angular coefficient seems ok now, the problem is that when I plot the fit now the resulting image is not correct.
[image]

#EDIT 2: Solved

```
plot 'file.txt' u 1:(log($2)), f(x)
```

That's the result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set logscale y` only set the y axis of the graph, not your data. You need to fit versus log(y):

```
fit f(x) 'file.txt' u 1:(log($2)) via m,q
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as per your suggestion (I had already tried previously but the plot was wrong and I thought i was missing something, this time I noticed that the angular coeff. was correct, and I secondly understood how to plot correctly).